# How to detect last 10 continuous keyboard events for specific key?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to find whether the user pressed specific key (ex: <kbd>Space</kbd>) continuously more than 10 times.

If user presses space key 10 times continuously then message box should be displayed.

I know I should use `KeyPress` event but no idea with continuous key press:

```
private void FormMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Is it `webforms` or `winforms`?

Comment: Do you mean "continuously" or "repeatedly"?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep track of the last key pressed and how many times it has been pressed so far. Check the counter and show the messagebox when it reaches 10.

```
private int _keyCount = 0;
private char _lastKey = default(char);

private void FormMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar != _lastKey)
    {
        _keyCount = 1;
        _lastKey = e.KeyChar;
        return;
    }

    _keyCount++;
    if (_keyCount < 10) return;

    MessageBox.Show("If only I could do my own homework!");
    _keyCount = 0;
}
```